# How to query json objects using Postgres JSONB column

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have JSON stored in a jsonb column:

```
{
  "processedResult": {
    "orderPayment": {
      "paymentType": "VISA"
    },
    "store": "US"
  }
}
```

What I have tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT myData -> 'processedResult' -> 'orderPayment' -> 'paymentType' 
FROM mytable
WHERE myData ->> 'processedResult' ->> 'store'  = 'US'
```

The WHERE clause seems to be incorrect.

Desired Output:

```
VISA
Mastedcard
```

Postgres Version: PostgreSQL 11.13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use

```
SELECT DISTINCT myData -> 'processedResult' -> 'orderPayment' ->> 'paymentType' 
FROM mytable
WHERE myData -> 'processedResult' ->> 'store'  = 'US'
```

Notice that `->` returns the selected `jsonb` value, whereas `->>` always returns a postgres `text` value (or `NULL`, or an error).